# How does robovm convert apps written in Java to iOS

Tags: java, robovm

I am intreseted in knowing how RoboVM (rip) works. How does it convert Java code to be run on iOS? What are binders and why does RoboVM sometime need them?

Comment: Seems a bit unrealistic to expect an explanation of the internals of a piece of commercial software here, doesn't it? You'll have more luck writing to the company and asking them to open source their product so you can find out for yourself.

Comment: @MarsAtomic RoboVM is defunct by now and was open source

Answer (score 0):

[RoboVM](https://github.com/robovm/robovm) is an LLVM frontend, which means it parses the bytecode and translates it to LLVM IR which is then compiled by the standard toolchain.

Bindings need to exist to support various OS features or 3rd party toolkits.

In the interest of full disclosure I work for a [company](https://www.codenameone.com/) that has its own [Java VM for iOS](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/vm) and there is some criticism of the RoboVM approach on that page.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I have to look up bytecode LLVM and standard toolchain.